# How to return enum value from unmanaged code

Tags: c++, vb.net, pinvoke

I have to return a enum value from C++ unmanaged code to VB.NET using P/Invoke.Can anybody suggest how to do it?

Comment: Which enum?  It is probably just a simple integer.